# How do i stop assuming bad things about the Future?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, psychology

I live in constant fear as i always assume that bad things will happen in the coming time . For example i was told by a recruiter that i might be called for a job interview in coming days, anytime. I am taking too much stress and anxiety about it as i am not prepared and feel that i will be rejected in it. I have made my life a living hell by constantly thinking about the future. I always think negative about future events in advance and live in extreme fear.

How to stop this permanently.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not the place for psychiatric help.

Comment: Philosophy and analytical psychology overlap.  For instance, Buddhism is called a philosophical system by many.

Comment: Philosophy and *everything* overlap, but there's a difference between answering questions *about philosophy* and answers questions *about everything*. How can I stop having anxiety about the future is not primarily a question about philosophy but rather a request for mental health assistance.

Comment: Agreed this is off-topic as asked, involves a highly specific personal situation.  Something like "useful ways to balance thinking about/planning for the future while living fully in the present" could be construed as a philosophical question.  I do see there is a "Cognitive Sciences" Stack Exchange where some variation of the original question could be on topic.

Answer (score 0):

My advice to you is to assume the worst, and then decide how you will handle it.  Picture the interview, see yourself "coming up empty" on question after question, and the interviewers scolding you for wasting their time, and having their security people escort you out, somewhat roughly, and only halfway through the scheduled interview time.  Is that close to the worst outcome you fear?  (In any case, picture the worst possible outcome you fear, and play it in your head like a movie, feeling the feelings.)

Now, imagine that you are sitting on the curb, right after that, right where security has dumped you. Feel the feelings of rejection, of worthlessness, panic about not having enough money to buy food, knowing you cannot pay rent and will be evicted and will have to live in a homeless shelter, and your former friends will shun you.  Feel whatever it is you are worried you will feel.  After a few minutes, release those feelings, and start thinking about what you will do, now that the worst has occurred.  What can you take action on to improve the situation from here?  Each day at the homeless shelter, will there be something you can go do to improve your situation?  Will there be a food bank you can visit to obtain food?  Think through and make peace with what you will need to do, when the absolute worst happens.

Now, the next step is to breathe a sigh of relief, that none of this has actually happened yet.  Find someone who knows most of the truth of your situation, and describe the worst case scenario you pictured to them.  Their reaction is unimportant; what's important is how do YOU feel about how all this sounds when you describe it?  Does it sound ludicrous, totally unrealistic?  Do you feel capable of improving upon this situation?

For movie therapy, I suggest watching "The Pursuit of Happyness" with Will Smith, which covers some of the homeless shelter ground.  Could you do at least some of what he did in the movie?

Now, when you start obsessing over the situation, think of the worst case and be amused at how ridiculous it seems.  Feel the emotion of amusement, at entertaining something so ridiculous.  Substitute amusement for the emotion of fear.  Then turn your mind to constructive steps you can take to create an outcome better than the ridiculous worst case you have pictured.  Repeatedly ask yourself a focusing question, such as, "what can I do today that would improve my chances for a better outcome?"  even, "what can I do RIGHT NOW that would improve my chances for a better outcome?"

To limit obsessing over this ONE interview circumstance, I also suggest asking yourself the question, "regardless of what happens with the recruiter and the interview in the coming days, what can I do today to improve my prospects for other situations that could be even better?"

You would do well to actually WRITE THESE QUESTIONS DOWN EACH DAY on a piece of paper, and then spend some time thinking, and write down whatever ideas come to you as answers.  This physical act of writing the question can be an important trigger for ideas. The physical act of writing down actions also helps your brain to believe in, and go to work on the ideas you come up with.

Make peace with your fear.  Make peace with the potential of very undesirable outcomes.  Accept them, as if they had already happened.  Accept the work you would need to do to recover from that worst outcome. Then change channels, think of how amusing and unlikely that worst outcome is, and then ask your mind to answering your focusing question about what you can do to improve your chances for a better outcome.

P.S. Some would suggest that you make your movie of the worst outcome even worse, to the point of being utterly ridiculous, and downright laughable.  I would encourage you to experiment with that as well, and see if that also helps.

Answer (score 0):

"*I always think negative about future events in advance and live in extreme fear. How to stop this permanently.*"

Guatama Buddha figured this out two and a half thousand years ago.  You should understand how to practise detachment, calm yourself down, and gain equanimity.  Once you're calm you can carry on with all the necessities of life as before, minus the worry and the worry-induced mistakes.

Detachment goes like this: I'm worried about nuclear war.  Hang on, I'm here by accident; the world is not my responsibility.  Now I'm calm I'll take care of the world anyway!

[Contemplations on Love, Compassion, Sympathetic Joy and Equanimity](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nyanaponika/wheel006.html)